# Removing specific strips in a double-strip plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, facet

I'm trying to remove the redundant "pro/retro" labels on the second row of panels on my plot. However, I still want to keep the top row of panel labels intact. I've tried for the past hour to selectively remove the 1st strip on the 2nd panel row and I was wondering if anyone here knows how to do this. See below for technical details.

I have the following plot:

[image: 2]

It was generated from the following data:

```
absBtwnDat <- structure(list(setSize = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), 
        Measure = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L), .Label = c("Actual", "Predicted"), class = "factor"), 
        Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L), .Label = c("fix", "forced"), class = "factor"), 
        JudgementType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("pro", "retro"), class = "factor"), 
        Accuracy = c(1.91388888888889, 2.95555555555556, 3.74861111111111, 
        4.37777777777778, 4.21527777777778, 3.0875, 2.85277777777778, 
        2, 2.99444444444444, 4, 4.77222222222222, 5.24444444444444, 
        5.18472222222222, 5.20277777777778, 1.98888888888889, 3, 
        3.97222222222222, 4.85972222222222, 5.70555555555556, 6.56944444444444, 
        7.27222222222222, 2, 3, 3.99444444444444, 4.99444444444444, 
        5.86944444444444, 6.75555555555556, 7.57777777777778, 1.96111111111111, 
        2.97777777777778, 3.78333333333333, 3.97222222222222, 4.22361111111111, 
        3.64722222222222, 3.68888888888889, 2, 3, 3.97222222222222, 
        4.67777777777778, 5.26944444444444, 5.4625, 5.8, 2, 3, 3.98333333333333, 
        4.87777777777778, 5.73055555555556, 6.48333333333333, 7.62916666666667, 
        2, 3, 3.98333333333333, 4.96666666666667, 5.96944444444444, 
        6.94444444444444, 7.93333333333333), LL = c(1.85, 2.87777777777778, 
        3.59861111111111, 4.15555555555556, 3.78888888888889, 2.73055555555556, 
        2.55555555555556, 2, 2.96111111111111, 4, 4.64444444444444, 
        5.01666666666667, 4.88333333333333, 4.88611111111111, 1.91111111111111, 
        3, 3.89444444444444, 4.73611111111111, 5.47777777777778, 
        6.20277777777778, 6.71666666666667, 2, 3, 3.96666666666667, 
        4.95555555555556, 5.65096686319131, 6.48333333333333, 7.17222222222222, 
        1.86637442123568, 2.92222222222222, 3.65, 3.61666666666667, 
        3.88333333333333, 3.17092476055122, 3.18888888888889, 2, 
        3, 3.92222222222222, 4.49444444444444, 5.0375, 5.09444444444444, 
        5.40555555555556, 2, 3, 3.92777777777778, 4.72222222222222, 
        5.52777777777778, 6.24444444444444, 7.37361111111111, 2, 
        3, 3.95, 4.88888888888889, 5.93333333333333, 6.88333333333333, 
        7.73065763697428), UL = c(1.95555555555556, 2.98333333333333, 
        3.84444444444444, 4.56666666666667, 4.6, 3.43611111111111, 
        3.17916666666667, 2, 3, 4, 4.86111111111111, 5.42777777777778, 
        5.48656054159421, 5.58611111111111, 2, 3, 4, 4.93888888888889, 
        5.83888888888889, 6.76944444444444, 7.6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.94166666666667, 
        6.88888888888889, 7.78888888888889, 1.98888888888889, 2.99444444444444, 
        3.87777777777778, 4.22777777777778, 4.53611111111111, 4.19722222222222, 
        4.20555555555556, 2, 3, 3.98888888888889, 4.78333333333333, 
        5.45555555555556, 5.79583333333333, 6.16666666666667, 2, 
        3, 3.99444444444444, 4.95, 5.85972222222222, 6.67222222222222, 
        7.80138888888889, 2, 3, 3.99444444444444, 4.98888888888889, 
        5.9875, 6.97222222222222, 7.98333333333333)), .Names = c("setSize", 
    "Measure", "Location", "JudgementType", "Accuracy", "LL", "UL"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -56L), class = "data.frame")
```

I visualized it using using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(data = absBtwnDat, aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(setSize)), 
                                    y = Accuracy, group = Measure, 
                                    colour = Measure))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Measure))+
  scale_x_continuous("Trial Set Size", breaks = 2:8)+
  scale_y_continuous("Accuracy (# Correct)", breaks = 0:8, limits = c(0, 8))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL), width = .1, size = .75)+
  scale_colour_grey(start = .8, end = .4)+
  facet_wrap(~JudgementType+Location, dir = "v")+
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Just to be certain, I've highlighted unwanted strip in the following image:

[image: 1]

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to use facet_wrap rather than facet_grid? Otherwise `facet_grid(Location~JudgementType)+` instead of `facet_wrap(~JudgementType+Location, dir = "v")+` should serve your purpose...

Comment: Excellent suggestion! But my preference would be to have all the labels displayed horizontally as in `facet_wrap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you'll only have one row of labels per panel, but they still include both words.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = absBtwnDat, 
         aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(setSize)), y = Accuracy, 
             group = Measure, 
             colour = Measure))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Measure))+
  scale_x_continuous("Trial Set Size", breaks = 2:8)+
  scale_y_continuous("Accuracy (# Correct)", 
                 breaks = 0:8, limits = c(0, 8))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL), 
            width = .1, size = .75)+
  scale_colour_grey(start = .8, end = .4)+
  facet_wrap(~JudgementType + Location, 
         dir = "v", 
         labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line=FALSE)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
  p1
```

Comment: Alternatively I could just mutate a variable which is a `paste0()` of the two variables and get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
k <- which(g1$layout$name=="strip-t-1-2")
g1$grobs[[k]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$label <- ""
g1$grobs[[k]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[1]]$gp$fill <- NA

k <- which(g1$layout$name=="strip-t-2-2")
g1$grobs[[k]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$label <- ""
g1$grobs[[k]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[1]]$gp$fill <- NA

library(grid)
grid.draw(g1)
```

[image]

Comment: This works with the exception that the borders around the strips (which are desired) point out that there's a now empty cell.

Comment: @ConnorG  There are no borders in your code. But they can be added. Add `strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black")` to the theme statement.